# Error while inserting Journal Transactions

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create a Journal Transaction of AR module from Shipment screen with new button, on this new button click, it should create Journal Transactions document with credit amount in one account and debit amount in one account, These two accounts are configured in shipment screen only.  but am getting below error. I am passing Project and all the other mandatory field values from code.

> Error: Inserting  'GL Transaction' record raised at least one error.
> Please review the errors. Project is Required but was not specified. Account '40000' used in the GL Transaction is mapped to Project Account Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either pass in the project from the shipment (if the journal transaction should hit the project) or pass in the default non project value.

for example if not setting the project from the shipment you can set your project field on the journal lines using the following:

```
myInTran.ProjectID = ProjectDefaultAttribute.NonProject();
```

If you are pulling the project from the shipment you need to set the journal tran lines for the ProjectID, TaskID, & CostCodeID fields.

Depending on the version of Acumatica you are using, you might not have CostCodeID. I think it was added in 2018R1.

If using the Non project value, the TaskID and CostCodeID are not required.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brendan, this solved the issue i was passing only ProjectID value but not TaskID.